# How to plot multiple subplots using for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I am very new to Python. I have a dummy dataset (25 X 6) for practice. Out of 6 columns, I have 1 target variable (binary) and 5 independent variables (4 categorical and 1 numeric). I am trying to view my target distribution by the values within each of the 4 categorical columns (and without writing code for separate columns - but with a `for` loop usage so that I can scale it up for bigger datasets in the future). Something like below:

[image]

I am already successful in doing that (image above), but since I could only think of achieving this by using **counters inside a `for` loop**, I don't think this is Python elegant, and pretty sure there could be a better way of doing it (something like `CarWash.groupby([i,'ReversedPayment']).size().reset_index().pivot(index = i,columns = 'ReversedPayment',values=0).axes.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`. I am struggling in handling this `ax =`  setting) Below is my non-elegant Python code (not scalable):

```
counter = 1
p = 0 
q = 0
fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,10))
for i in categoricals[:-1]:
    CarWash.groupby([i,'ReversedPayment']).size().reset_index().pivot(index = i,columns = 'ReversedPayment',values=0).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,ax = axes[p][q])
    counter = counter+1
    q = q+1
    if counter==3:
        q=0
        p = p+1
```

Here's the full data generation code:

```
d = {
    'SeniorCitizen': [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] , 
    'CollegeDegree': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] , 
    'Married': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] , 
    'FulltimeJob': [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1] , 
    'DistancefromBranch': [7,9,14,20,21,12,22,25,9,9,9,12,13,14,16,25,27,4,14,14,20,19,15,23,2] , 
    'ReversedPayment': [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0] }
CarWash = pd.DataFrame(data = d)


categoricals = ['SeniorCitizen','CollegeDegree','Married','FulltimeJob','ReversedPayment']
        numerical = ['DistancefromBranch']
CarWash[categoricals] = CarWash[categoricals].astype('category')
```

My other minor problem is getting data labels. Any comments, advice much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data, a block of [code-formatted text with the output of `print(df)` is much more useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I just added the data generation code for full data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to make your code less repetitive for many potential columns is to make a function that plots on an axis. That way you can simply adjust with 3 parameters basically:

```py
ncols = 2
col_show = 'ReversedPayment'
col_subplots = ['SeniorCitizen','CollegeDegree','Married','FulltimeJob']
```

Now we can compute the rest from there. Note that [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) allows to iterate directly on several arrays at the same time, and [`np.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) iterates on the 2D axes array as if it were 1D.

```
nrows=(len(col_subplots) + ncols - 1) // ncols
fix, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows, figsize=(7.5 * ncols, 5 * nrows), sharey=True)
axes_it = axes.flat

for col, ax in zip(col_subplots, axes_it):
    plot_data(CarWash, col_show, col, ax)

# If number of columns not multiple of ncols, hide remaining axes
for ax in axes_it:
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Now in this case the `plot_data` is very simple it barely needs to be a function. But you can complexify it easily this way, and it allows to keep the data logic somewhat separate from the rest which is basically housekeeping.

- `DataFrame.value_counts()` does the same as `GroupBy.size()` but it’s slightly more explicit
- `unstack()` pivots an index level to columns − you did this with `.reset_index().pivot()`. So now you have your column `a` (here always `ReversedPayment`) as columns, the other column as index
- Finally `.plot.bar()` is the same as `.plot(kind='bar')`, `ax` specifies which axes to plot on, `rot=0` avoids rotating the indexes and you already know `stacked=True`.

```
def plot_data(df, a, b, ax):
    counts = df[[a, b]].value_counts().unstack(a)
    counts.plot.bar(ax=ax, stacked=True, rot=0)
```

As you can see `subplots(sharey=True)` allows all plots to have the same scaling on the y axis and thus makes comparing the various plots easier.
[image: resulting plot]

The other advantage of using an iterator `axes_it` is that it continues where you stopped iterating on it − suppose you had only 3 `col_subplots`, there’s 1 left, and now you can call `ax.axis('off')` on it:
[image]

Comment: @Climbali - Thanks for the answer. Learnt something new today. Followup Q: How to annotate data labels in plot()? (% and #). % would be more useful.

Comment: You have a lot of examples here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html
With % you could do `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=100))`

Comment: @Climbail - I am getting an error saying: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'. When I am running the code `plot_data` section. Panda version: '0.25.3'

Comment: Yes it’s from a newer version. You can upgrade or stick with `GroupBy([a, b]).size()`